# How to tell Mathematica: continue NDSolve using values when you reach limit?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to do a fairly complex integration. The details aren't relevant, but are at https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ASTRO/bc-integrate-init.m and https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ASTRO/bc-integrate.m for reference.

When I run the NDSolve command, this happens:

```
sol = NDSolve[{posvel,accels},planets,{t,-366*500,366*500}, MaxSteps->100000, AccuracyGoal -> 50];

NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 100000 steps reached at the point t == -65522.6.

NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 100000 steps reached at the point t == 65285.8.
```

How do I tell Mathematica: treat the data at t == -65522.6 and t == 65285.8 as initial conditions and continue solving the equation for the next 65000+ time units, and so on, until you've reached the interval I originally requested: -366*500,366*500 (or -183000, +183000).

I realize the results won't be as accurate as if I'd just used more steps, but I'm running out of memory, so I want to NDSolve this piecewise. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Well, OK, but I was hoping for a more general and automatic method for NDSolve in general, not just this specific example.

Comment: Perhaps, it is possible to use the information in [NDSolve Components and Data Structure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#2125957807) to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Are you assuming that the OP only wants the solution at the two endpoints?  I had assumed that he wanted the solution throughout the region but wished to compute and store it in pieces.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Correct. I want to solve it for a large range of values, but only a little bit at a time to avoid the error.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I think he wants the entire solution on {-366*500, 366*500} but in bite-sized pieces that he can store somewhere.  After each piece is stored, I believe he wants to run a new computation with the final result of the previous piece as the initial condition for the next piece.  I am confident that this can be done in a straightforward manner using the NDSolve Components but would be interested in knowing a better way.  In fact, it can be done using NDSolve in the usual manner too,

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, let me suggest the `"Extrapolation"` method, with one of the implicit methods as a base integrator.  It's a bit slower, but it seems to do a fairly accurate job, at least compared to the NASA data provided in the Github files.  And it completes the integration in 28,000 to 45000 steps, a considerable savings over the `Automatic` method.

#### General procedure

*First,* I quit the kernel to get a measure of the memory usage.  The OP's initialization file was put in an initialization cell (not shown), so that it would be automatically initialized for each trial.

*Second,* set the base integration method in `basemethod`.

*Third,* execute the last code block, which calls `NDSolve`, collects some data, and outputs a couple of tables, one of time and space usage and another comparing the result to the NASA data.

I had to increase `PrecisionGoal` a bit, to get an accurate result.  One might push it up a little more, but soon one will also have to increase `WorkingPrecision`, too, which will slow down the integration even more.

```
Quit[]

basemethod = < method goes here >

nasa = {1.764338998100163*^-01, -3.499459824403553*^-01, -2.055213183324884*^-01};
mem = MaxMemoryUsed[];
time = First@ AbsoluteTiming[
    sol = NDSolve[{posvel, accels}, Array[planet, 9], {t, -366*500, 366*500},
       Method -> {"Extrapolation", Method -> basemethod}, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 10, MaxSteps -> 100000, AccuracyGoal -> 50];];
mem = MaxMemoryUsed[] - mem;
steps = planet[1]["Grid"] /. First[sol] // Length;
size = ByteCount[sol];
TableForm[{{time, mem, steps, size}},
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"time", "memory", "steps", "size"}}]
With[{n = nasa, p = planet[1][360*20] /. First[sol]},
 TableForm[Transpose@{n, p, (p - n)/n},
   TableHeadings -> {{"x", "y", "z"}, {"NASA", "sol", "rel. error"}}]
 ]
```

#### `"LinearlyImplicitMidpoint"`

The `"LinearlyImplicitMidpoint"` method is the fastest.

```
Quit[]

basemethod = "LinearlyImplicitMidpoint"
(* run the above *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### `"LinearlyImplicitModifiedMidpoint"`

The `"LinearlyImplicitModifiedMidpoint"` method takes the fewest steps and therefore the least memory.

```
Quit[]

basemethod = "LinearlyImplicitModifiedMidpoint"
(* run the above *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### `"LinearlyImplicitEuler"`

Well, I tried this one. There's not much to recommend `"LinearlyImplicitEuler"` over the other two.  Still, I'll share the results to save others the trouble.

```
Quit[]

basemethod = "LinearlyImplicitEuler";
(* run the above *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### The `Automatic` method (OP's)

The `Automatic` method used 200,000 steps for only one third of the interval in just over 14 sec.; it also used over 900MB of memory.

Comment: Thanks! I'd considered running every combination of method and submethod to see which combination was fastest, but felt it would be too painful.